# How to find the area of a triangle from plane equation using vector product?

Tags: vectors, area, cross-product

> Find the area of a $S$, the part of the plane $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$ in the first octant where $x,y,z>0$. Also the parameters $a,b,c>0$. The final answer should be: $$\sqrt{\frac{a^2b^2}{4}+\frac{a^2c^2}{4}+\frac{b^2c^2}{4}}$$
>
> [image]

I think there're several ways to do it, but I think this could be solved by doing vector product. We know the norm of vector product gives us parallelogram so to get the area of $S$, (triangle) we need to divide the final answer by $2$.

The problem I'm running into is determining the two vectors.

First, I tried getting the points $a,b,c$ (this is bit confusing as these are also the parameters in the plane equation but they appear in the drawing). So I think it should be:
$$
b=\left(0,\frac{y}{b},0\right)\\
a=\left(\frac{x}{a},0,0\right)\\
c=\left(0,0,\frac{z}{c}\right)
$$
Which would produce vectors:
$$
AB=\left\langle -\frac{x}{a},\frac{y}{b},0\right\rangle\\
AC=\left\langle -\frac{x}{a},0,\frac{z}{c}\right\rangle
$$
But the vector product doesn't give the desired solution:
$$
AB\times AC=\left\langle \frac{yz}{bc},-\frac{xz}{ac}, \frac{yx}{ba}\right\rangle
$$
What am I missing?

Comment: The part that is confusing you is the part where you wrote that this is confusing. Let's find the point where the plane meets the x-axis, lets name that point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. For any point $(x,y,z)$ on the x-axis, we have $y=0$ and $z=0$, so together with the plane equation we get $\frac{x_1}a + \frac0b + \frac0c = 1$. So we have $x_1=a$. And now your confusion should go away: The point where the plane meets the x-axis is labeled "a" because that is exactly the value of the x-coordinate of that point! The same goes for the points where the plane meets the y- and z-axis, resp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertices of your triangle are $(a,0,0)$, $(0,b,0)$, and $(0,0,c)$. So, what you have to do is to compute the vector product $\bigl((0,b,0)-(a,0,0)\bigr)\times\bigl((0,0,c)-(a,0,0)\bigr)$, which is $-(bc,ac,ab)$. It's norm is $\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}$ and halving it gives the result that you're after.

Comment: But why the vertices are like that? why they're not fractions?

Comment: @Yos Just look at the diagram! The vertex located at the $x$-axis is $(a,0,0)$. This is confirmed by the fact that $\frac aa+\frac0b+\frac0c=1$.